# Make an element inside a linked element not a link

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
<li id = 'search'<?php if(strcmp($PageType,'Search') == 0){print("class='active'");} ?> 
    onclick = "location.href = '<?php $AdvSearchRoot = $Root . "/search/advancedsearch.php"; echo $AdvSearchRoot; ?>'">
    <form id = 'searchform' action = '<?php $SearchRoot = $Root . "/search/search.php"; echo $SearchRoot; ?>' method = 'get'>
        <input type = 'text' id = 'searchBox' name = 'searchTerm' placeholder = 'Search' required></input>
        <input type = 'submit' value = 'submit'></input>
        <a id = 'AdvancedSearch' href = '<?php echo $AdvSearchRoot;?>'>Advanced Search</a>  
    </form> 
</li>
```

Basically I want to be able to click the inputs on the form without it taking me to the link in the li element.

*what the code above outputs*:

[image: what the code above looks like]

Comment: What element is the link?

Comment: What is the point of having the _onclick_ attribute that changes the location if the only contents (of the list item) are an anchor (link) and inputs? is there supposed to be other content (e.g. text, images, etc) inside the list item?

Comment: @blackandorangecat the li and also the a elements

Comment: @Sam Onela so that you can click the li element as well as 'advanced search' and it does the same thing.

Comment: @Sam Onela Derp, meant to say the li element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to have the click handler change the location without affecting the form inputs is to check the tagname of the element clicked. If it is the list item, then change the location (otherwise do nothing).

```
<li id = 'search'<?php if(strcmp($PageType,'Search') == 0){print("class='active'");} ?> 
onclick = "if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') location.href = '<?php $AdvSearchRoot = $Root . "/search/advancedsearch.php"; echo $AdvSearchRoot; ?>'">
```

This utilizes the implicit *event* argument of the click handler, as well as [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), and its property [.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName), plus [String.toUppercase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) to check the tag name of the element that was clicked on.

See it demonstrated in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9bnQIwXHhIz3YqMJUBf9).